# How does Dask utilize RAM when writing to a parquet file?

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I am using Dask for 2 reasons:

(1) To reduce the RAM memory usage when Pandas dataframe is assigned to 100 million rows of data.
(2) Able to analyze data that is bigger than RAM.  (Currently, I am using 50GB RAM.)

I also need to save these 100 million rows of data to parquet files.

Does Dask load the entire dataframe to memory in order to write to a parquet file?
How efficient is the memory usage when writing to a parquet file?

Thanks in advance.

> Here is the code to write to a compressed parquet file.

```py
path_out = "/content/drive/MyDrive/AffinityScore_STAGING/staging_affinity_block1_from_DASK2.gzip"
dask_df.to_parquet(path_out, compression='gzip', write_metadata_file=False)
```

Comment: how is the dask.dataframe being created? a code example would help. have you tried this? it should just work...

Comment: dataframe is created reading a parquet file. i am doing some data transformation and need to write back to a parquet file.  the time it takes to write it to a file is pretty fast. my major concern is the RAM usage while it writes.